# Copying HTML characters instead of typing their code

Tags: html

Suppose, I want to use a special html character &rArr;

Instead of typing it in the html file as &rArr;, we can also copy paste the character ⇒ in the editor.

Is there any problems with the latter approach?

(I use notepad++ and dreamweaver as editors)

Comment: As long as you use UTF8 everywhere, that's fine.

Comment: i got the answer from the comment. but why the down votes? this question was not asked before and hence typed as new question.

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: Mention what editor you are using.

Comment: @Esko, added that in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a font that has the characters you are using. Depending on the html editor, Choosing a text editor that supports `UTF-8`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use charset / page Encoding as **UTF-8** to do so, For instance:

`contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"`